# Why does PHP_CodeSniffer only allow me to have a Magento copyright at the top of my code?

Tags: magento2, copyright, phpcs

**When I try to use my own copyright I get this warning when running phpcs:**

```
"0: line: 3, col: 1, Copyright is missing or has wrong format"
```

**But if I use Magento copyright, I get no warning.**

**No Warning:**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
```

**Warning:**

```
/**
 * Copyright © MyCompany, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
```

**Actual Code**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MyCompany All rights reserved.
 * See License for license details.
 */

namespace MyCompany\MyApp\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Gets current products Categories
 */
class CalculatorLogic extends Template implements 

ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Category $categoryModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryModel = $categoryModel;
    }
    
    /**
     * Gets current products Categories
     *
     * @return Category[]
     */
    public function getProductCatagory()
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
        $arr =[];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cat = $this->categoryModel->load($category);
            $arr[] = $cat->getName();
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

**phpcs results**

```
{"totals":{"errors":0,"warnings":1,"fixable":0},"files":{"\/var\/www\/html\/mage\/app\/code\/MyComany\/MyApp\/ViewModel\/CalculatorLogic.php":{"errors":0,"warnings":1,"messages":[{"message":"Copyright is missing or has wrong format","source":"Magento2.Legacy.Copyright.FoundCopyrightMissingOrWrongFormat","severity":5,"fixable":false,"type":"WARNING","line":3,"column":1}]}}}
```

Comment: can you share any one file with the code?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Did anyone find the solutions?

Comment: @JustinCollins are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MyCompany All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyCompany\MyApp\ViewModel;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Perhaps its just the way I have phpcs configured.

Comment: Kindly check you did not put any extra space over there.

Comment: I am certain, there is no extra space.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Magento uses its own CopyrightSniff where they require text 'Copyright © Magento' :)

Answer (score 0):

overwrite vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard/Magento2Framework/Sniffs/Header/CopyrightSniff.php file's process.
giving

```
public function process(File $phpcsFile, $stackPtr)
{
    return;
}
```

please do it if you are bother with text error.